# Load value from dimens.xml and make it negative

Tags: android, xml

In an xml document, is there any way to load a value from dimens.xml and make it negative?
For example, if I have:

```
<dimen name="x">20dp</dimen>
```

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
android:layout_marginRight="-@dimen/x"
```

So I in de facto get:

```
android:layout_marginRight="-20dp"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That is not possible in standard layout XML. You could retrieve the dimension value in Java, multiply it by `-1`, and apply it in Java.

You could even do that in the form of a custom attribute (e.g., `yourapp:layout_negativeMarginRight`) in your own custom subclass of `ViewGroup`, if you really wanted. This would seem to be overkill.

---

**UPDATE**: This is now somewhat possible via [data binding expressions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html):

```
android:padding="@{0.75f * @dimen/icon}"
```

It does not work for margins or any other layout attributes due to the lack of binding adapters which you can implement. See [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=200890).

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare mentioned there's no way to achieve this in XML without data binding.

I'm dropping this Kotlin snippet here for those that want to achieve this programmatically:

```
textView.updateLayoutParams<RecyclerView.LayoutParams> {
    marginEnd = -context.resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.nestedParentListAdapterDivider)
}
```

Change the `RecyclerView.LayoutParams` to the parent ViewGroup you're using followed by `.LayoutParams`.